# OpenModelica and FMU cross compilation (Linux->Windows)

Tags: linux, windows, openmodelica, fmi

I would like to compile in Ubuntu a FMU for Windows (32 and 64bits).

I read in the OpenModelica User's Guide Release v1.11.0 (https://openmodelica.org/newss/179-february-6-2017-openmodelica-1-11-0-released):

"Added OMEdit support for FMU cross compilation. This makes it possible to launch OMEdit on a remote or virtual Linux machine using a Windows X server and export an FMU with Windows binaries."

"Cross compilation of C++ FMU export. Compared to the C runtime, the C++ cross compilation covers the whole runtime for model exchange."

[image: OMEdit options]

How can I do the cross compilation?

Should I install anything to get a Windows option in the "Platform" section?

Thanks!!!

Edited:
"sudo apt-get install mingw-w64" adds the Mingw compilers.
Is it possible to add other compilers? For example: Clang for Windows.

Comment: I don't quite get what you want, it seems you want in a Windows OS to be able to use the CLANG for compilation instead of GCC. But that's really not cross-compilation, is just another compiler. Currently we don't support CLANG for Windows but we will look into it as is way faster and consumes less memory than GCC. Visual Studio compiler workns, but currently only for the Cpp runtime.

Comment: @adrianpop Thanks for the quick answer! I want to export large-scale FMUs (Model Exchange) for Windows. But I could export bigger models using cross compilation from Ubuntu (i686-w64-mingw32) than using normal compilation in Windows (MSVC or GCC).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mingw: sudo apt-get install mingw-w64
The option will appear in the dialog window.